# Can homebrew be sold in NSW, Australia?

Tags: food-safety

Assuming a limited licence application is approved, can *homebrew* be sold in NSW, Australia?

Comment: I am not a lawyer with expertise in food laws in Australia. BUT.... assuming you are actually able to obtain such a license, would it matter *how* the brew is brewed? I would think that would be dealt with during the license application process, so I would think getting the license automatically means "yes". But you should probably consult a local expert.

Comment: The licence is for the selling and serving part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep sure can but you will need to obtain permits and pay excise. The ATO covers it all here: http://www.ato.gov.au/businesses/content.aspx?doc=/content/00180139.htm&pc=001/003/095/005/001&mnu=0&mfp=&st=&cy=